# Spring Boot - custom error page doesn't show up when the app is started in a standalone way (java -jar)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with a custom Error Page - handled by a simple Controller implementing `ErrorController`:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public ModelAndView error() {
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

}
```

This runs fine when the application's main class is started within Eclipse. However when I package the app to a fat jar by executing `mvn clean install` and then start it by calling `java -jar myapp.jar` the custom error page doesn't appear - I only see the standard Whitelabel Error Page.

Comment: Tested with versions: 1.2.5 and 1.3.0 of Spring Boot

Comment: I found there's inconsistencies with the way boot apps behave depending on how they're ran. FE, launching it by running `main` wont' function the same as if you use `mvn spring-boot:run`. The compiled jars seem to have issues with urls (issues w/ `/`s) too which aren't present when packaged as a war. I know that's no terribly helpful but maybe you can try to make a couple small changes and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is that I need to run it via `java` command.

Comment: I used `@RestController` instead of `Controller` and returned an `error String`. I tested with 1.3.0.RELEASE and I can see the error. May be it is something to do with your error file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, albeit I have still no idea why the initial code behavior is different between running the Main class from Eclipse and running the application using fat jar and `java -jar` command.

To the point: I found out in the logs that SpringBoot finds my `CustomErrorController` as a handler for `/error` path. However in the next step he called the view defined in the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` class. The solution was just to change the view name e.g. from `error` to `errorPage`:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH, produces = "text/html")
    public ModelAndView error() {
        return new ModelAndView("errorPage");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

}
```

Somehow the view in the `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` overrides the custom created view with the same name. A secondary question is - why I don't see this behavior happen when I start my app in Eclipse?